# How to find the MGF of the max of a set of i.i.d. exponential random variables

Tags: exponential-distribution, extreme-value, order-statistics, moment-generating-function, iid

As the title suggests, I would like to find the MGF of the max of iid exponential random variables. Assume $Z=\max(x_{1},...,x_{n})$, where $x_{i}$ is distributed as exponential($\beta$) and has pdf $\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-x/\beta}$. I already found the pdf of the max: $\frac{n}{\beta}e^{-x/\beta}[1-e^{-x/\beta}]^{n-1}$.

To find the mgf, I tried $\frac{n}{\beta}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{tx}e^{-x/\beta}[1-e^{-x/\beta}]^{n-1} dx$, but this has no closed-form solution. Someone told me to try expanding the $[1-e^{-x/\beta}]^{n-1}$ by using Binomial Theorem, so here is my attempt at that:

$\frac{n}{\beta}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{tx}e^{-x/\beta}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}(-e^{-x/\beta})^k dx$

$=-\frac{n}{\beta}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{x(t-\frac{1}{\beta}-\frac{k}{\beta})} dx$

$=-\frac{n}{\beta}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}[\frac{1}{ t-\frac{1}{\beta}-\frac{k}{\beta} }e^{x(t-\frac{1}{\beta}-\frac{k}{\beta})}]_{0}^{\infty}$

Assuming $t<\frac{k+1}{\beta}$,

$=-\frac{n}{\beta}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}\frac{1}{t-\frac{1}{\beta}-\frac{k}{\beta}}$

Where do I go from here? I would like to find a "nice" closed-form solution if possible, one that doesn't contain integrals or sums. I would like to find the mgf using integration with binomial expansion if possible, but I am open to other solutions if they are easier/simpler.

Comment: You can make it a little nicer by changing $n/\beta$ to $n$ at the beginning and replacing the denominator with $\beta t-1-k$ at the end.

Comment: An approximation can be obtained using the MGF of the Gumbel distribution since up to a linear scaling $Z$ nearly follows a Gumbel distribution when $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Using your formula for say $n < 40$ and then the Gumbel approximation would give an good precision. The "small n" part is easily implemented using a recursion for the binomial coefficient when $k$ runs from $0$ to $n-1$. Mind that the formula lacks a $(-1)^k$.